# Load DOM content

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Is there a way I can use Javascript to load a site's UI content in DOM? For example

```
<code>      
  <h1>Google</h1>
</code>
```

Retrieving "Google" (which has a h1 tag) in my Javascript code.

Comment: Retrieving from where? google.com? If so, no you can't do that.

Comment: Do u just want html and are you using jQuery on your site?

Comment: Question is too vague, post a real example of what you are trying to do. Is it different servers? What did you try?

Comment: See my answer below: var h1 = $('h1').html();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Access DOM on your own page**

To answer your exact question:

```
var h1 = $('h1').html();
```

Yes, you might add jQuery to your site and use it's selector, like so:

```
$( "#foo" )[ 0 ]; // = document.getElementById( "foo" )
```

**Access DOM of other page**

This is not so easy, because of Cross Domain Policies.
Anyway, you will find out, if it is blocked.
Try an Ajax query to get the website content, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
baseUrl = "http://www.somedomain.com/";
$.ajax({
    url: baseUrl,
    type: "get",
    dataType: "",
    success: function(data) {
        // play with data
});
```